# Hadoop Hue bulk upload CSV format for HBase

Tags: csv, hbase, hue

I want to upload CSV file into HBase via `Hue Bulk Upload`. But I did not find what is the format of input data. I've tried:

```
'3b47522d851c85af39abefb500016a90','bools:bool_col',true,'ints:tinyint_col',1,'ints:smallint_col',2,'ints:int_col',3

':key','3b47522d851c85af39abefb500016a90','bools:bool_col',true,'ints:tinyint_col',1,'ints:smallint_col',2,'ints:int_col',3
```

Once I submit file, the GUI just refreshes, but does not load the input file.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I've figured out.

My table `hbasealltypessmall` has these column family types:

```
'bools', 'ints'
```

So, the CSV should have this format:

```
:key,bools:bool_col,ints:tinyint_col,ints:smallint_col,ints:int_col
3b47522d851c85af39abefb500016a90,true,1,2,3
```

**Important: Space between column families is not allowed!**

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer, i have faced 'Internal error processing mutateRows' error in HBase Browser more than 5 hours fighting with that finally found your answer, it is working for me too.

Comment: Is there is anyway to find Bulk upload progress? Because Hue - HBase browser does not show any loading panel while uploading

Comment: Honestly, I do not know. Normally, I see after uploding the result

Comment: No Problem, I also doing the same thing. I Just curious to ask that's it